# Having problems with Bios Password for Fujitsu Lifebook E734

Tags: bios, passwords, password-recovery

I have bought a Second hand Fujitsu lifebook E734 and it is locked, the Bios and Windows with a password. I have tried to contact the seller but I can´t reach him leaving me with the only option to try by myself to get the password.

Can anybody tell me what can I do? I tried to obtain the master code the way is described in bios-pw.org but it doesn't work (this is the code the system gives me: 0270-0516-4162-7160-4032-8371), I have also tried to use a recovery CD with Windows but its not working due to the BIOS settings and I already reset the bios clock but the password is still there. Help please, I´m desperate!

I think I threw away my money...

Thank you!

Comment: If you think about it, all we have to go on is your statement that you have already tried everything.  In that case, what else could we tell you?  If you've tried everything and nothing works, then nothing works.  Do you want people to suggest random things you've already tried?

Comment: My knowledge is limited in this field. Be cause I have tried everything that is in my hand, it doesn't mean there is no other option! thnaks!

Comment: No other options other than what?  If you don't describe what things you tried, the only way for people to suggest things is to duplicate what has already been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, seems quite a messy case, anyway probably a laptop.

OK, here is something to try

- first shut the machine and take the power cord off, and take the big battery out
- then open the bottom cover and find somewhere there the CMOS battery, and disconnect it
- lastly ensure discharging the possible residual power from the mobo pressing the power button for some 5secs
- now, if everything went smoothly, the BIOS CMOS settings should be got defaulted and the BIOS password cleared
- next do all the disassembling procedure backwards
- and, after that, boot the machine, and hopefully get to the Windows logon

But, how to go on, if not booted successfully, or the Windows password not known, will be another stories ...

Answer (score 0):

If you could use a screwdriver, you could see if you find the case for the RAM-memory, perhaps there is a reset button or to switch off the bios battery ?